# Variables in routeProvider URL argument

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have this url in my app.js:

```
$routeProvider.when('/:language/boat-rental-:departure', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/boat-rental.html', 
    controller: 'BoatListCtrl'
});
```

So, the application can process Urls like `/en/boat-rental-malaga`.

Now, I would like to replace boat for a concrete type of boat, such as sailboat, motorboat or catamaran. I mean, I would like to process urls like:
`/en/sailboat-rental-malaga`.

How can I do something like (which is not working):

```
$routeProvider.when('/:language/:boatType-rental-:departure', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/boat-rental.html', 
    controller: 'BoatListCtrl'
});
```

Comment: did you try throwing another path segment in after `boatType`?

Answer (score 0):

I´m sorry, Maybe my code was cached and it didn´t work before, but now it´s working for me as depicted above:

```
$routeProvider.when('/:language/:boatType-rental-:departure', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/boat-rental.html', 
    controller: 'BoatListCtrl'
});
```

URL like:  `/en/sailboat-rental-majorca`